# php instant search, display data return with radio button

Tags: php, mysql, search, radio-button

I have an instant search built using php. Basically what I would like to do is have each item that is returned by the search have a radio button attached to it. When the button is clicked by the user I would like to have the name of that item stored in an array. I cannot seem to find much useful documentation for doing something like this. Here is my current search.php code.

```
<?php

mysql_select_db("wesco");

$searchArray = explode(" ", $_POST['searchterm']);
$query = "";

foreach($searchArray as $val) {
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(1);
$search = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($val));
if (!empty($query)) {
    $query = $query . " AND"; 
}

$query = $query . "`keywords` LIKE '%$search%'";
}

if (!empty($query)) {
$find_parts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `parts` WHERE $query");
}
if(empty($query)){
$searchArray = explode(" ", $_POST['searchterm']);
$query = "";

}

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($find_parts))
{
$name = $row['name'];

echo "<center>$name</center><br />";
}


?>
```

Comment: Why add items to an array on radio button click? Only one radio button might be chosen at one time inside radio button group. Do you mean checkboxes? What are you expecting to do with the said array? Why are you posting the whole code instead of an example output? That would have increased readability and help us to understand the problem.